# Remote program execution

Tags: windows-7, telnet, remote-access

On Windows 7 how to allow someone from different network to start execution of certain .exe file that already exists and for which path can be provided?

You can assume that subject involved will have same OS.

Remote machine is behind a firewall and you can assume that some ports can be forwarded.

Requirements:

1. subject that will start execution remotely needs to have simple way to do so without installing any additional software if possible
2. 1. does not mean that everyone should be able to execute it (simple authentication is needed)
3. process to set up machine that will execute program can be more complex if it will make it more user friendly to subject mentioned in 1.
4. last but most important: subject mentioned in 1. must not be able to execute, read or change anything else on remote system, again if possible

So far only thing that I could find that would maybe suit for this purpose was telnet which can satisfy first three requirements if I'm not wrong but I'm not sure that last requirement can be fully met using it.

Comment: Okay, I've found solution.

Comment: I'm running webserver with website on machine that contains program that needs to run on client's request.
I'm using PHP's execute() to enable to him to with click of a button to start executing that file.
I'm using some tested login script so I can assume that login form is secured as much as it's possible.
Is this safe if only thing that client can do on website is to log in, log out and click to run the program?
I will implement function that will disable client to start spaming clicking that button indefinetly to cause unintended effect on server.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/free-download/?filename=remoteexecute.exe

Intelliadmin provides a great remote execution program that can be easily used to remotely execute .exe files over a lan network. An network admin account is needed on both computers with the same user and pass

Syntax:

```
remoteexecute.exe -h [host] -u [user] -p [pass] [options] [filename] [arguments]
```

Options:

```
 -h The remote host name or IP

 -u Username *

 -p Password *

 -e Don't load users environment variables

 -l Don't load users profile

 -c Copy file to the remote host

 -cs Run process in the console session

 -n Run process as hidden

 -sf [filter] Run process in session where user matches the filter

 -i Return immediately, and don't wait for process to terminate

 -sa Run process under the system account

 -su Run process as the session user

 -q Quiet mode.
```

Required options - *

Answer (score 0):

That program does not seem to use any type of encryption. Sending that data in plain-text is asking for trouble.

Windows 7 at least offers 128-bit RDP encryption:
http://www.howtogeek.com/175087/how-to-enable-and-secure-remote-desktop-on-windows/

However, this article mentions TLS/1.0 which is nearly identical to SSL v3 - both of which are considered broken. I recommend searching for a solution that can implement TLS/1.1 and later on a Windows 7 machine.